# Unable to redirect to login after clearing session

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I'm using passport js for session. When I click the logout button, the session is cleared but the redirect doesn't happen. I know the session is cleared because when I refresh it is redirected to the login page.

I even see that the `/login` request function is called because of the redirect but the page still remains at the index page.

This is the logout code:

```
    app.get('/logout',function(request,response){
       // request.session.destroy();
       console.log("logout called");
       request.logout();
       response.redirect('/login');

})
```

The function called after redirect(it sends the `login.html`):

```
    app.get('/login',function(request,response){
    console.log(request.isAuthenticated()+ " LoginIsAuth");
    if(request.isAuthenticated()){
        response.redirect('/');
    }
    else{
       response.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/login.html");
    }
})
```

Comment: maybe you're using ajax to logout?!

Comment: @TilekbekovYrysbek. nope. i'm not

Comment: @TilekbekovYrysbek.I didnt get a answer from anyone, so I sent a response to controller(angularjs) in the client side instead of redirecting  and am moving to another page using `$window.location.href`. will there be a problem if i do that